# NUMEROS ALEATÓRIOS EM PHP EXCLUINDO UM NUMERO DA LISTA

Tags: php, array, random

Boa tarde, preciso pra um trabalho da escola fazer uma busca de 7 numeros de 1 a 20, excluindo um numero da lista.

Exemplo: 7 Numeros aleatorios de 1 a 20, excluindo o numero 5 da lista. Que me retorne 7 numeros todos diferente de 5.

````
function random($nNumeros, $nQuant) 
{ 
    $aRand = array(); 
    for ($i=1; $i<=$nQuant; $i++) { 
        $aRand[$i] = $rand = rand(1, 20) ; 
        while (count($aRand) < $nNumeros) 
            if (!in_array($rand, $aRand)) 
                $aRand[] = $rand; 
            else 
                $rand = rand(1, 20); 
    } 
    return $aRand; 
} 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r(random(7,1)); //1
?>```
````

Comment: O que exatamente é `$nQuant`? Poderia descrever em texto o que seu código está fazendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, uma seria construindo um dicionário que ignore os inválidos e outro seria fazendo um loop, descartando os inválidos.

---

Irei fazer o primeiro, que segue a lógica um pouco contrária do seu código atual. Então, para isso você precisa usar o `range` para criar o dicionário inicial:

```
$dicionario = range(1, 20);
```

Isso criará um array com valores de 1 até 20.

---

Depois, precisará eliminar os valores inválidos. Então, podemos assumir que o `$excluidos` é algo como `array(1, 2, 3)` (ou seja: 1, 2 e 3 não podemo ser escolhidos). Para isso pode usar o `array_diff`:

```
$dicionario = array_values(array_diff($dicionario, $excluidos));
```

O `array_values` é utilizado para evitar "intervalos" no array.

---

Então, depois, pode gerar um número de 0 até o máximo que existe no $dicionario, utilizando `random_int`.

---

Então, no final terá algo como:

```
function Gerar(int $Quantidade, int $Maximo, array $Excluidos) : array {
    
    // Cria o array inicial
    $dicionario = range(1, $Maximo);
    
    // Exclui os inválidos
    $dicionario = array_values(array_diff($dicionario, $Excluidos));
    
    $resultado = [];
    
    // Gera a quantidade de número definidas
    for ($i = 0; $i < $Quantidade; $i++) {
        
        // Gera um número aletorio de 0 até a quantidade existente no dicionario.
        $id = random_int(0, count($dicionario) - 1);
        
        // Salva no "resultado"
        $resultado[] = $dicionario[$id];
        
        // Remove o número gerado da lista, afim de não gerar novamente o mesmo número
        unset($dicionario[$id]);
        $dicionario = array_values($dicionario);
        
    }
    
    return $resultado;  
}
```

Que pode ser utilizado como:

```
// Gerar *7* numeros, de 1 até *20* e excluindo o *5*:
echo implode(",", Gerar(7, 20, [5]));
```

Resultado:

```
20,9,19,6,13,18,14
```

São 7 número de 1 à 20, sem repetição e sem o 5.

---

Observe que não foi adicionado qualquer verificação na função, então gerar mais do que a quantidade existente ou excluir mais do que possível não retornará erros claros, apenas o Warning do próprio PHP.